# Assembly working with strings, checking result

Tags: assembly

I'm not sure how to even formulate the question but I've recently started learning assembly and I've got to the point where I work with strings of bytes/words and my final result will as well be a string of bytes/words...
My question is, how do I check that my program returned the correct result? Is there any way?
I've just finished solving a problem that sounds like this:
I have the string S: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and I have to compose the string D whose elements represent the sum of each two consecutive bytes of S so D:3, 5, 7, 9, 11
How do I check that I got the right result?

Comment: That's a question not necessarily specific to assembly language. You can verify it by hand (do enough examples where you've convinced yourself it's working if you have too many possibilities). Or write an independent program (even in another language) that reads and verifies the results. In this specific case, it looks like doing it by hand with small sample sizes is the quickest way to go.

Comment: Well you see, assembly is a low level language and you can't say that it looks very close to anything else I know. I am used to check my simple hexadecimal number result via CPU(tasm, tlink, tdebug) so I thought I can check the string result somehow like that

Comment: OK, it's a little unclear what you're asking. Exactly what are you trying to check? If your program outputs values, you can check those visually.

Comment: I want to check what is stored in the variable D (there should be stored a string of bytes 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)

Comment: You can check strings in your debugger too.

Comment: How? that's the real question

Comment: Since you mentioned turbo debugger ... that has a data display pane where you can see the contents of memory as hex and text. See the bottom left pane [here](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~rares/asm25.bmp).

Comment: Oh ok so if my final result is stored in es:di... I don't know exactly what to look for in the memory contents. I was used only to check the registers on the right table.

Comment: Are you saying that you actually have a string "1, 2, 3, 4, ..." where it's an ASCII `1`, an ASCII comma, and ASCII space, etc? If so, then just get your trusty ASCII table out (Google "ASCII chart") and look for those codes in memory.

Comment: You can look at the value of `es` and `di` in the registers window and then use those for the data display.

Comment: WOah it worked! Thank you all. I was looking for the result in the es as well but I couldn't find anything. BUT instead of a register name, I got my result stored in 48AD. Maybe I'm too new to assembly to understand what's that yet. But thank you all for your help! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the correctness of your hand-written assembly implementation (which is a really good idea), you can write the equivalent program in a different language. Give both programs the same input, pipe each output into a file, and run a `diff`-utility on the files.
If you want to trace your program though its execution, you can run the program in a debugger. It won't have the amenities of a debugger with high-level source-code, but you should be able to  get the debugger to display register contents and memory.
In `gdb` you can use `i(nfo) reg(isters)` to show register state.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, I just haven't learnt yet how to use files and how to output info xD

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to check the result is to display as many chars in a line as specified in the string

```
lea si, d
mov cx, 4 ;replace size with the amount of elements in D; mustn't be zero
new_row:
push cx
mov al, 10
int 29h
mov al, 13
int 29h
lodsb
or al, al
jz e
mov cx, ax
xor ch, ch
mov al, 46 ;the character shown as many times as specified in the string (here: a dot . )
next_char:
int 29h ;the advantage of this function is, the output always shown at the screen, it cannot be pipelined.
loop next_char
e:
pop cx
loop new_row
exit:
mov al, 10
int 29h
mov al, 13
int 29h
```